# Convert this python dictionary into JSON format?

Tags: python, json

I have a python dictionary which I want to convert into json.

Python dictionary:

```
{"20090209.02s1.1_sequence.txt": [645045714, 3559.6422951221466, 206045184], "20090209.02s1.2_sequence.txt": [645045714, 3543.8322949409485, 234618880]}
```

Desired output:

```
{
       "file_name":"20090209.02s1.1_sequence.txt",
       "file_information": [645045714, 3559.6422951221466, 206045184],

    {
       "file_name":"20090209.02s1.2_sequence.txt",
       "file_information": [645045714, 3543.8322949409485, 234618880],

    }
}
```

Tried with `json.dumps` but I didn't get the desired output.

Comment: @AndyHayden: There is more going on here. This is not a pretty-printing problem.

Comment: Your output is *invalid* JSON; did you mean for this to be a list of dictionaries instead?

Comment: @MartijnPieters eeew what *is* it?!

Comment: @AndyHayden: I've made an educated guess below. Let's see if that is good enough.

Comment: Yes the desire output I mentioned was invalid. The answer given by @Icfseth was what I wanted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to first create a structure with the correct format:

```
import json

dict_ = {"20090209.02s1.1_sequence.txt": [645045714, 3559.6422951221466, 206045184], "20090209.02s1.2_sequence.txt": [645045714, 3543.8322949409485, 234618880]}
values = [{"file_name": k, "file_information": v} for k, v in dict_.items()]
json.dumps(values, indent=4)
```

Note that the desired JSON output does not look valid to me. Here's the output for this code:

```
[
    {
        "file_name": "20090209.02s1.1_sequence.txt", 
        "file_information": [
            645045714, 
            3559.6422951221466, 
            206045184
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "file_name": "20090209.02s1.2_sequence.txt", 
        "file_information": [
            645045714, 
            3543.8322949409485, 
            234618880
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. I will accept your answer whenever I can.

Answer (score 1):

Split out your key-value pairs into separate dictionaries:

```
json.dumps([{'file_name': key, 'file_information': value} for key, value in yourdict.iteritems()])
```

Note that the *order* of your output will be arbitrary (dictionaries have no fixed ordering). You may want to sort the output to produce a predictable list:

```
from operator import itemgetter

data = [{'file_name': key, 'file_information': value} for key, value in yourdict.iteritems()]
data.sort(key=itemgetter('file_name'))
json.dumps(data)
```

This produces:

```
>>> data = [{'file_name': key, 'file_information': value} for key, value in yourdict.iteritems()]
>>> data.sort(key=itemgetter('file_name'))
>>> json.dumps(data)
'[{"file_name": "20090209.02s1.1_sequence.txt", "file_information": [645045714, 3559.6422951221466, 206045184]}, {"file_name": "20090209.02s1.2_sequence.txt", "file_information": [645045714, 3543.8322949409485, 234618880]}]'
>>> print json.dumps(data, indent=4)

[
    {
        "file_name": "20090209.02s1.1_sequence.txt",
        "file_information": [
            645045714,
            3559.6422951221466,
            206045184
        ]
    },
    {
        "file_name": "20090209.02s1.2_sequence.txt",
        "file_information": [
            645045714,
            3543.8322949409485,
            234618880
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Hm I want to add those keys called file_name and file_information.

Comment: I think you're missing the point here, the dict format and the json format are different :)

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted. +1

Comment: I'd upvote as it is the same solution as lcfseth, but everything on one line ? really ?