# Convert Python Dictionary to JSON format

Tags: python, json

I am creating a Python dictionary from a dataframe and the results contain a few thousand entries;

```
oxford_english = df.set_index('id')['name'].to_dict()
# Example result:
{12345: 'companyA'}
```

I need to convert the dictionary by changing the current keys and values into the following format:

```
{"id": "12345", "name": "CompanyA"}
```

I know how to change values and keys in a dictionary but I can't figure out how to split the entries into new key value pairs.

The reason for all of this is because I need to pass the dictionary as JSON to a Web API.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert this python dictionary into JSON format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167297/convert-this-python-dictionary-into-json-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want a json you should use the method 'to_json' of DataFrames:

df.to_json().

Here the documentation: [pandas.DataFrame.to_json](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

Comment: That was it! Thank you! I couldn't figure out, via the docs if I can select only certain columns from the DF to convert to JSON. Am I missing it? I am dumping the desired columns to a new DF as a work around.

Comment: You could just create a dataframe with the desired columns from the original: newdf = df.iloc[:, 0:5]  (here i get the columns from 0 to 5). Then use the method with the new dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your title seems misleading. If I didn't misunderstand, you want get a format of dictionary from DataFrame.

```
In [25]: df = pd.DataFrame({'id':[12345, 12346], 'name': ['CompanyA', 'CompanyB
    ...: ']})

In [26]: df
Out[26]:
      id      name
0  12345  CompanyA
1  12346  CompanyB
In [29]: df.to_dict(orient='records')
Out[29]: [{'id': 12345, 'name': 'CompanyA'}, {'id': 12346, 'name': 'CompanyB'}]
```